# Use Google Maps API to display Street View of a house based on an address

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I am trying to use Google Maps to display a streetview of a house based on an address.  I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielattard/R59mB/) based on this [tutorial](http://www.jaycodesign.co.nz/js/using-google-maps-to-show-a-streetview-of-a-house-based-on-an-address/).  The fiddle is working to display the default, initial address, but I cannot figure out how to pass the new address into the street view code when the button is pressed.

Here is the HTML:

```
<h3>Enter an Address to view the street view</h3>
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <textarea name='new_address' class="address">150 Glen Road, Toronto</textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="change_street" value="Change Street View Address" />
</form>
<div class="map_container">
    <div id="map_canvas_cont">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="pano_cont">
        <div id="pano"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
var panorama;
var addLatLng;
var showPanoData;
var panorama;

function load_map_and_street_view_from_address(address) {              
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var gps = results[0].geometry.location;
            create_map_and_streetview(gps.lat(), gps.lng(), 'map_canvas', 'pano');
        }
    });
}

function create_map_and_streetview(lat, lng, map_id, street_view_id) {

    panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"));
    addLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var service = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
    service.getPanoramaByLocation(addLatLng, 50, showPanoData);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: addLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        streetViewControl: false,
        keyboardShortcuts: false
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(map_id), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: addLatLng
    });

}

function showPanoData(panoData, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        $('#pano').html('No StreetView Picture Available').attr('style', 'text-align:center;font-weight:bold').show();
        return;
    }
    var angle = computeAngle(addLatLng, panoData.location.latLng);

    var panoOptions = {
        position: addLatLng,
        addressControl: false,
        linksControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        pov: {
            heading: angle,
            pitch: 10,
            zoom: 1
        },
        enableCloseButton: false,
        visible: true
    };

    panorama.setOptions(panoOptions);
}

function computeAngle(endLatLng, startLatLng) {
    var DEGREE_PER_RADIAN = 57.2957795;
    var RADIAN_PER_DEGREE = 0.017453;

    var dlat = endLatLng.lat() - startLatLng.lat();
    var dlng = endLatLng.lng() - startLatLng.lng();
    var yaw = Math.atan2(dlng * Math.cos(endLatLng.lat() * RADIAN_PER_DEGREE), dlat) * DEGREE_PER_RADIAN;
    return wrapAngle(yaw);
}

function wrapAngle(angle) {
    if (angle >= 360) {
        angle -= 360;
    } else if (angle < 0) {
        angle += 360;
    }
    return angle;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    load_map_and_street_view_from_address("150 Glen Road, Toronto");

    $('#change_street').click(function () {
       alert("How do I pass the new address to the street view code?");
    });

});
```

Can someone please explain to me how to fix this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielattard/R59mB/) so that I can pass a new address with the button press?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be multiple solutions, I would suggest to store the maps-, marker and panorama-instances, then you only need to update their properties on further calls instead of creating new instances.

calling the function on button-click:

```
load_map_and_street_view_from_address($('textarea[name="new_address"]').val());
```

replacement for `create_map_and_streetview` & `showPanoData`:

```
function create_map_and_streetview(lat, lng, map_id, street_view_id) {
    var goo=google.maps,
        map=$('#'+map_id),
        pano=document.getElementById("pano"),
        addLatLng = new goo.LatLng(lat, lng),
        myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: addLatLng,
        mapTypeId: goo.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        streetViewControl: false,
        keyboardShortcuts: false
    }
    if(!map.data('gmap')){
      //store the instances per $.data
      map.data('gmap',new goo.MVCObject());
      map.data('gmap').set('panorama',new goo.StreetViewPanorama(pano));
      map.data('gmap').set('service',new goo.StreetViewService());
      map.data('gmap').set('map',new goo.Map(map[0], myOptions));
      map.data('gmap').set('marker',new goo.Marker({
                                                  map: map.data('gmap').get('map'),
                                                  animation: goo.Animation.DROP,
                                                  position: addLatLng
                                                })
                      );
    }else{
      map.data('gmap').get('map').setCenter(addLatLng);
      map.data('gmap').get('marker').setPosition(addLatLng);
      //always create a new panorama
      //otherwise the panorama will be broken as soon as there is no picture available 
      map.data('gmap').set('panorama',new goo.StreetViewPanorama(pano));
    }

    map.data('gmap').get('service')
      .getPanoramaByLocation(addLatLng, 50, function(panoData, status){ 
         if (status != google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
            $('#pano').html('No StreetView Picture Available')
              .attr('style', 'text-align:center;font-weight:bold').show();
            return;
        }
      var angle = computeAngle(addLatLng, panoData.location.latLng);

      var panoOptions = {
        position: addLatLng,
        addressControl: false,
        linksControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        pov: {
            heading: angle,
            pitch: 10,
            zoom: 1
        },
        enableCloseButton: false,
        visible: true
      };

      map.data('gmap').get('panorama').setOptions(panoOptions);
    });

}
```

---

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/R59mB/4/**](http://jsfiddle.net/R59mB/4/)

Comment: Wow! That is awesome Dr.Molle.  Works perfectly, and I managed to learn a few things from what you've done for me.  You're the best, thank you.

Comment: Oh, glad I found this. Just what I needed and was just going to try to ask this question.