# How to show the street view of an address when I don't have latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

There's another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625013/use-google-maps-api-to-display-street-view-of-a-house-based-on-an-address) about showing the google streetview of an address but all the links are broken.

From looking at what they were doing, would I have to geocode the address and then look up the street view for those coordinates?

If all I have is an address, and I need to programmatically show the street view of the house, what is the most direct way to accomplish it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want something similar to this (geocoding): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps StreetView from Address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384664/google-maps-streetview-from-address)

Comment: Related question: [Facing the targeted building with Google StreetView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495948/facing-the-targeted-building-with-google-streetview)

Comment: Related question: [Request main road / curbside StreetView panoramas instead of back alleys from API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176327/request-main-road-curbside-streetview-panoramas-instead-of-back-alleys-from-ap)

Comment: Thank you geocodezip. I didn't see "Google Maps StreetView from Address". Your answer is really great with code and everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you said is correct. You feed the geocoder the address and it gives you back a JSON containing the full name along with the coordinates.

Response example from the geocoder: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA

And now you have the coordinates which you can use to feed the street view.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro

Hope it helps:)